# SwiftUI - Adding dimmer view behind custom alert

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a view modifier for reusable custom alert which works as expected. I now want to add a dimmer view in between presenting view and alert view i.e. view behind the alert which covers full screen and disables any clicks on the presenting view.

I tried adding background on the presenting view when alert is presented, but nothing is happening.

***Custom alert view modifier, view extension and view model:***

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CustomAlertView: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(alertContent())
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func alertContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if self.$isPresented.wrappedValue {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle").resizable().frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0).padding(.top, 30).foregroundColor(.cyan)

                    Text("Error title").foregroundColor(Color.black).font(.title2).bold().lineLimit(nil).padding([.leading, .trailing], 24.0).padding(.top, 16.0)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("There was an error while processing your request.").foregroundColor(Color.black).font(.body).lineLimit(nil).padding([.leading, .trailing], 18.0).padding(.top, 16.0)
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { self.$isPresented.wrappedValue.toggle() }) {
                        Text("Ok").foregroundColor(.white).font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    }.padding(.bottom, 25.0)
                }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .clipped()
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5.0)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2)
                    .frame(width: 328.0)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func customAlert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        return modifier(CustomAlertView(isPresented: isPresented))
    }
}

class CustomViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAlert = false
    
    func doSomething() {
        // Sets showAlert to true incase of network disconnect or some query failure.
        self.showAlert = true
    }
}
```

***Content view:***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomViewModel = CustomViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            Button(action: { viewModel.doSomething() }) {
                Text("Start").foregroundColor(Color.red).font(.title)
            }.padding(.bottom, 100.0)
        }
        .background(viewModel.showAlert ? Color.gray : Color.clear)
        .customAlert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert)
    }
}
```

Here, ContentView is the presenting view since it's what is presenting the alert. I want to add a grayish sort of view/dimmer view covering full screen and it will be below the presented alert. When dimmer view is present and I click on "Start" button in ContentView, it should be disabled. I don't know if I can achieve this by modifying the custom alert view modifier, hence I was trying to add a background color to ContentView, but nothing seems to be happening. I have too much of code in the view model and content view, so I removed most of it and kept what I thought was needed.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work without some modification. Would you be able to post a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, modifying and adding in few mins.

Comment: I added working code. You can either save everything into one file or create a contentview file and save content view struct into it and rest everything into another file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a view behind the custom alert view modifier. Adding code here incase if someone comes looking for it in future.

I removed ".background(viewModel.showAlert ? Color.gray : Color.clear)" from my content view since I eventually wanted the logic to be part of custom alert view modifier and not add it to every view. In my customAlertView, I modified the body function as below:

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.overlay(self.$isPresented.wrappedValue ? Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea() : nil)
        .overlay(self.$isPresented.wrappedValue ? alertContent() : nil)
}
```